# Code first one-to-many with two of same entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

Excuse my confusing title, but its not easy to say it in short.

I'm having problems defining a many-to-many relationship in my code first model.
This is my first project using the code first framework, and I need some help.

I got two models, `Item` and `Trade`. And the story behind it all is that im building a item trading website.

A trade involve one or many items beeing sent from person A to person B, and one or many items are sent back from person B to person A, completing the trade.

One item belongs to one trade only, but one trade can have many items.

This is how my models look so far.

**Item**

```
public class Item
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int TradeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TradeId")]
    public virtual Trade Trade { get; set; }
}
```

**Trade**

```
public class Trade
{
    public int TradeId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Item> ItemsToSend { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Item> ItemsToReturn { get; set; }
}
```

But when trying to run `update-database` I get the following error.

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Items_dbo.Trades_TradeId". The conflict occurred in database "MyDB", table "dbo.Trades", column 'TradeId'.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Try removing the Data Annotation. Or, if your DB is not populated yet, drop it and create it again.

Comment: It seems like you're database already has data in it and the migration is failing because of the constraints.

Comment: Thanks all. But I thought this line in `Global.asax` made sure that the DB is beeing dropped. `Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<DBContext>());`

Comment: I tried removing `[ForeignKey("TradeId")]` and now my `update-database` run successfully. But there is no `Trade` table beeing created in the DB...

Comment: @Martin not sure if it's possible with data annotations, but I know that you have to specify explicitly the relationships between Item and Trade using fluent API. Many-to-many between trade and itemstosend, and many-to-many between trade and itemstoreturn, correct?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it for now by just adding a flat structure of items and trades. Like a many to many on items and trades.

Since I know the owner of each item, I can also sort out sender and returner by adding senderId and returnerId on the trade.

This is how my model looks like now.

**Item**

```
public class Item
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Trade> Trades { get; set; }
}
```

**Trade**

```
public class Trade
{
    public int TradeId { get; set; }
    public virtual UserProfile SendUser { get; set; }
    public virtual UserProfile ReturnUser { get; set; }     
    public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

This works for now..

Answer (score 0):

This: "One item belongs to one trade only, but one trade can have many items." sounds like one-to-many?

If you can do without the back-reference from Item to Trade then the mapping will be a lot simpler.

This model will map without any configuration:

```
public class Trade
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Item> ItemsToSend { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Item> ItemsToReturn { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Inserting data using this code:

```
        var trade = new Trade
        {
            ItemsToReturn = new [] { new Item{ Name = "Item to return 1"}, new Item{ Name = "Item to return 2"}},
            ItemsToSend = new [] { new Item{ Name = "Item to send 1"}, new Item{ Name = "Item to send 2"} }
        };
        context.Trades.Add(trade);

        context.SaveChanges();
```

Will produce an Item table looking like this:

[image]

And a Trades table containing a single row with a single Id column.

If you need to navigate from an Item to the Trade it belongs to you could do that doing a query.

E.g to get the Trade that Item with id = 3 belongs to you can do this:

```
using (var db = new TradingContext())
{               
    var tradeOfItem3 = db.Trades.
        FirstOrDefault(t => t.ItemsToReturn.Any(i => i.Id == 3) || t.ItemsToSend.Any(i => i.Id == 3));
}
```